# when setting netbeans label text to static String, UI designer does not display it

Tags: java, string, netbeans, label

I am trying to set the contents of a label's text to a static String but the UI designer does not display it when I do this.

1. Open file in edit mode.
2. create public final static String SOME_VALUE = "my label";
3. switch to design mode
4. examine a component's properties, and click the labelText property.
5. change to custom code, and enter the variable (SOME_VALUE)

the code runs properly, but when you view it in design mode, it is shown as "label text" instead of my static string.  This makes designing problematic when looking at long strings, as the sizing is off.

Has anyone found a way to make this work?

Comment: I should add I am using netbeans 6.9.1

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think that you *can* make this work. You're asking to have design mode depend on code created outside of the Matisse code generator.

Comment: Simulate it by setting the string in design mode to be something of appropriate length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time back I solved this king of problem, There is no way in netbeans to read programetically coded string directly to UI designer. But there is a work around!

1. Create a property file
   1.1 Right-click package->New->Other->Other->Properties File
   1.2 Insert your key-value pair there
2. In UI designer, select label
   2.1 Properties->text->Resource Bundle
   2.2 Select appropreate fields
   2.3 you are done!
3. Assigning bundle value to static string
   public static String myString = java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle("PATH-To-Bundle-file").getString("NAME-OF-THE-KEY");

Good luck :)